# How to deploy Consul on AWS EC2 instance over Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

**Note: This is not the Consul by HashiCorp** it is a different project: http://consulproject.org/

*I'm not sure if this is a specific problem to the consul project or if anyone with knowledge of Ansible and EC2 would be able to solve it.*

I am trying to deploy a Consul instance to an Amazon EC2 instance via the Installer. I've followed the instructions found here: https://github.com/consul/installer

I'm doing this from a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 which has Python 2.7 installed on it.

I downloaded the .pem file from AWS which is a Private Key for SSH authentication. I can SSH into the server via ssh -i [path to .pem file] ec2-user@[ip address of EC2 instance]

I've installed Ansible. When I run:

```
sudo ansible-playbook -v consul.yml -i hosts
```

> "Please login as the user \"ec2-user\" rather than the user
>   \"root\".\r\n\r\n"

**However, I have edit my group_vars/all file to include root_access: false so I'm not really sure what else needs to be done.**

My git diff looks like this from the repository:

```
diff --git a/group_vars/all b/group_vars/all
index 85bf74d..cb3db37 100644
--- a/group_vars/all
+++ b/group_vars/all
@@ -10,10 +10,10 @@ locale: en_US.UTF-8
 # General settings
 env: production
-root_access: true
-deploy_user: deploy
+root_access: false
+deploy_user: ec2-user
 home_dir: "/home/{{ deploy_user }}"
-deploy_password: test
+deploy_password: <some really great password>
 deploy_app_name: test
 deploy_server_hostname: 127.0.0.1
 consul_dir: "{{ home_dir }}/consul"
@@ -27,7 +27,7 @@ shared_public_dirs:
   - "system"
   - "ckeditor_assets"
-ssh_public_key_path: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
+ssh_public_key_path: "[path to .pem file]"
 # Ruby
 ruby_version: 2.4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not run the `ansible-playbook` command with `sudo`. If the tasks in the playbook need root access (on the remote/managed host), then add `become: true` where necessary (i.e. either at a task level, play level, or in your Ansible config)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update the ansible_user.
To do this in this case, I added this line to the group_vars/all file

```
ansible_user: ec2-user
```